# Is it possible to fix all problems on vscode from Flutter

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

Is it possible to fix all the problems that are detected by the linter on vscode (Flutter) ?
I use to fix them one by one with the quickfix button, but now I have too many problems to be fixed one by one.

[image: vscode quickfix]

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use the below command to see all the available suggestion

```
dart fix --dry-run
```

and this is fix all of them

```
dart fix --apply
```